# Why does the google auth2 object return isSignedIn.get() as true after calling signOut()?

Tags: google-signin

```
function signOut() 
{
   var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();

   auth2.signOut().then(function () {
     console.log('User signed out.');
     console.log(auth2.isSignedIn.get()); // returns true
     console.log(auth2.currentUser.get().isSignedIn()); // returns true
   });
}
```

I am currently signed into the google account and if my understanding is correct, signing out of an application does not sign out the google account on other applications in the browser. So if `auth2.signOut()` implies signing out of the website its used in, why does `auth2.isSignedIn.get()` or `auth2.currentUser.get().isSignedIn()` return true in the console?

If it implies the user is signed into the google account then how can I check for sure if the user is signed out of the website using the `auth2` object?

I'm using the sample from https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in